# Question with downvotes used as "good" audit

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I was just given this review audit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/8891842

I thought the question was too broad, so I voted to close. I failed the audit, since Stack Overflow seems to think it was a good question. However, it looks like the question had three downvotes when I reviewed it. Shouldn't questions with downvotes never be used as audits?

This bad audit caused me to be review banned for a whole 7 days, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless something's changed since Shog answered

[Failed a Reopen Question audit — sure looks like "Not a real question" to me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168366/failed-a-reopen-question-audit-sure-looks-like-not-a-real-question-to-me)

it was stated that the voting threshhold is between 5 and 15 votes, and that downvotes only applies to Close/Reopen audits, so even though it has downvotes, it's within that threshhold.

Also, one failed audit shouldn't auto-ban you, so you must have missed some other audits as well.

Comment: Realistically, any question can have some downvotes so auto ignoring downvoted posts isn't an intelligent filter.

Comment: Yeah I did fail one a few days ago (also a bad audit) but I didn't make a post about it. Seven days seems a bit extreme either way, though.